# Do all homogeneous spaces have homogeneous compactifications?

Tags: gn.general-topology, homogeneous-spaces, compactifications

Let $X$ be a separable metric space which is *homogeneous*, i.e. for every two points $x,y\in X$ there is a homeomorphism $h$ of $X$ onto itself such that $h(x)=y$.

A compactification of $X$ is a compact metric space which contains a dense homeomorphic copy of $X$.

Does $X$ have a homogeneous compactification?

Examples of homogeneous compactifications include the circle for the real line, the torus for the plane etc.

Comment: Isn't a countably infinite discrete space a counterexample?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you want a connected example:

A surface of infinite genus has no homogeneous compactification.

Indeed first observe a dense locally compact subset has to be open.

So the surface has to be open, and by homogeneity the compactification is a closed surface. But an open subset of a closed surface has (each component of) finite genus.

Answer (score 12):

The countable discrete space $\omega$ is a counterexample.

Suppose $Y$ is a homogeneous compactification of $\omega$, with $X \subset Y$ being homeomorphic to $\omega$.  As $Y$ is infinite, it necessarily contains at least one limit point.  So by homogeneity, every point of $Y$ is a limit point of $Y$, including those that are in $X$.  But since $X$ is dense in $Y$, this implies that each point of $X$ is a limit point of $X$.  Thus $X$ is not discrete, a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, of course. I was only thinking about connected spaces. Perhaps that will be a separate question.